# Material-ui datagrid filter not working in temporary drawer

Tags: datagrid, material-ui, drawer

I'm using datagrid component in "temporary" drawer (drawer's variant prop is temporary). In this case datagrid filter is not functioning. If I change "temporary" to "permanent" it works but I need temporary one.
[image: Please see attached image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been resolved in Material UI v5.